# What's an alternative to Seq.iter so that I can return the result of the operation for the last item?

Tags: f#

**What's an alternative to Seq.iter so that I can return the result of the operation for the last item?**

Seq.iter returns a unit. However, I want to iterate through my collection and return the last result.

**Consider the following code:**

```
let updatedGrid = grid |> Map.toSeq
                       |> Seq.map snd
                       |> Seq.iter (fun c -> grid |> setCell c
```

NOTE: SetCell returns a new Map:

**Here's the actual code:**

```
let setCell cell (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    grid |> Map.map (fun k v -> match k with
                                | c when c = (cell.X, cell.Y) -> { v with State=cell.State }
                                | _ -> v)

let cycleThroughCells (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    let updatedGrid = grid |> Map.toSeq
                           |> Seq.map snd
                           |> Seq.iter (fun c -> grid |> setCell c 
                                                      |> ignore) 
    updatedGrid
```

Again, I just want to take the result of the last operation in the iter function

**[UPDATED]**

I think this works (using map):

```
let cycleThroughCells (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =

    let updatedGrid = grid |> Map.toSeq
                           |> Seq.map snd
                           |> Seq.map (fun c -> grid |> setCell c) 
                           |> Seq.last
    updatedGrid
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a fold instead?  `x |> Seq.map f |> Seq.map g |> Seq.last` is the same as `x |> Seq.last |> f |> g`, as long as `f` and `g` have no side effects.

Comment: @ kvb - Honestly, I don't understand Folds yet. It looks cryptic to me.

Comment: A fold takes an element of a sequence plus some state and applies a function to get the updated state to use with the next element of the sequence.  Otherwise, if `setCell` outputs a modified map but doesn't have any side effects, then you'd be throwing away all of the modifications except the one made by the last call.

Comment: A `fold` is basically equivalent to a basic `foreach` loop. It is just implemented internally as recursion. That means instead of mutable state that you modifiy outside of a loop, you get the state from the previous loop as input, and you produce a new state for the next iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, it seems like you almost certainly want a fold so that the updated grid is passed to each successive call; otherwise the modifications are all dropped except for the last one.

I think this would do the trick:

```
let cycleThroughCells (grid:Map<(int * int), Cell>) =
    grid 
    |> Map.toSeq
    |> Seq.map snd
    |> Seq.fold (fun grid c -> grid |> setCell c) grid
```

and if you reorder the arguments to `setCell` so that the `grid` argument comes first then the last line can just be `|> Seq.fold setCell grid`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think one exists but you can define your own using `fold`:

```
let tapSeq f s = Seq.fold (fun _ x -> f x; Some(x)) None s
```

Comment: I posted an update. I haven't tested it yet though. What do you think?

Comment: `Seq.last` will blow up if the sequence is empty.

Comment: @ScottNimrod - Yes your approach will work if the sequence is non-empty.

Comment: `Seq.last` will blow up if the sequence is empty, but `Seq.tryLast` will not.